# spatial data and sql server : very slow queries

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, spatial-query

Currently I am using SQL Server and having issues, i have a table Adress with 12M of addresses; when i look for one addresses; its take 3 or 4 minutes to find it. i have to look for more than 40000 adressess averyday in my table. so Sql server dont help me to resolve this problem.
i think about using an other SGBD maybe MongoDB, but i dont have any idea if it will work or not. my goal is to find every query in less than 2 sec.

My query :

```
SELECT TOP 1 adresse 
FROM   (SELECT 
       geography::Point(p.latitude, p.longitude,4326).STDistance(geography::Point(Cast(Replace('28,5259799957275', ',', '.') AS FLOAT)
       , Cast(Replace('28,5259799957275', ',', '.') AS FLOAT), 4326)) AS rn, 
p.adresse 
FROM   [adressespositions] p) ph 
WHERE  ph.rn < 10
```

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[adressespositions](
    [idgeocodage] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [latitude] [float] NULL,
    [longitude] [float] NULL,
    [adresse] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [dateajout] [datetime] NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [idsource] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the RAM of my server : 128 GB.

how can i make this query very fast ? or i have to use an other SGBD ?

Comment: Check [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-2017). There must be a `Point` column in the table with a spatial index and the query must be written in a specific way. Without a spatial index all spatial databases will be slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new column with the GPS point in `GEOGRAPHY` type (instead of recreating it on every `SELECT`). Then create a `SPATIAL INDEX` on that column and performance should spike.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.adressespositions ADD GPS GEOGRAPHY

UPDATE T SET
    GPS = GEOGRAPHY::Point(T.latitude, T.longitude, 4326)
FROM
    dbo.adressespositions AS T

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SI_adressespositions_GPS ON dbo.adressespositions (GPS)
```

Creating the spatial index might take a while if you have many records. Also, a spatial index requires a primary key on that table (will have to create one if you don't have one already).

Then you change your select like the following:

```
DECLARE @FilterGPS GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(
    Cast(Replace('28,5259799957275', ',', '.') AS FLOAT),
    Cast(Replace('28,5259799957275', ',', '.') AS FLOAT), 
    4326)

SELECT TOP 1
    P.adresse,
    Distance = P.GPS.STDistance(@FilterGPS)
FROM
    [adressespositions] AS P
WHERE
    P.GPS.STDistance(@FilterGPS) < 10
ORDER BY
    2 ASC
```

Comment: This probably won't use the spatial index [based on the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-2017). There's no need to filter by the distance when the query *orders* by the distance and selects the TOP 1 result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe the engine is smart enough to figure out that `ORDER BY 2 ASC` actually means the `STDistance()` function. It can be explicitly set if otherwise tho. If you don't filter you might get results with distance higher than what you want.

Comment: No it isn't, check the docs. This code is similar to the example used for a query that can't use a spatial index. There must be a null-check to filter out rows that may return a `NULL` distance at least.

Comment: It uses the index properly, just validated it. The OP will let us know if not otherwise.

Comment: Yes, because `P.GPS.STDistance(@FilterGPS) < 10` *does* filter out NULLs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - what exactly is your contention? Through empirical evidence, the query uses the index. There is an implicit `not null` check in the where clause. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the distinction you're trying to make here.

Comment: @BenThul none? There's no contention? My last comment is identical to yours `Yes, because P.GPS.STDistance(@FilterGPS) < 10 does filter out NULLs.`. I posted a link to the docs with the actual requirements for a nearest-neighbour query which is *tricky*. If you don't fulfill all of them the index *wont'* be used. If you put another condition before the distance check, no index. If you use OR, no index

Comment: Based on your tone, you could have fooled me. First comment - "index likely won't be used". Second comment - "nope, you're still wrong". Third comment - "well... technically you're right".

Comment: @BenThul should I remove the upvote then? If you agree with this answer, upvote. The vote count is the same it was 2 hours ago

Comment: i did all your suggestions, now its working perfect (y)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using float for latitude and longitude why not change your table structure with spatial datatypes like Geography or Geometry. Then after you can use spatial index on newly created table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: Post all that in the *answer*, not the comments. Check EzLo's answer